# How to merge multiple csv files into an single csv file with single header also remove duplicates based on the certain column

Tags: java, csv, merge, duplicates, zip

I have more then 100 csv files in an directory, which have same column names and i want to merge them into an single csv file with single header how can i do that in java.
I have written an program which will extract all the csv files from multiple zip folders in an directory now i want to combine those multiple csv file into an single csv file with single header.
Also i want to remove duplicates in them if there are any based on the comparison of certain columns.

Eg:

CSV1:

Id  Name    Number
1   Raj         1234
2   Ramesh      2345
3   Jayesh      3467

CSV2:

Id    Name      Number
1     Ganesh     4756
2     Suresh     7575
3     Jayesh     9999

Similar to this i have 100 of csv files and i want to combine it into single csv with single header 
Like this:

Id   Name      Number
1     Raj        1234
2     Ramesh     4321
3     Jayesh     4567
1     Ganesh     4756
2     Suresh     7575

As we can see that **jayesh** will appear only once as he has entries in both csv files. (here i have used the **Name** for comparison in this example)
This is just an example which has only 3 columns but in my real csv i have more then 20 columns.

How can i do it in Java program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why your data are on the same line : "Id Name Number 1 Raj 1234 2 Ramesh 2345 3 Jayesh 3467" and not with a record on each row. Then, you say it is CSV. CSV is Comma Separated Value. So I would expect that your columns are separated with a ",". So I will consider that your data is in fact like this :

```
Id,Name,Number
1,Raj,1234
2,Ramesh,2345
3,Jayesh,3467
```

I will consider you did not make the effort of presentation in your question.

Moreover, I don't understand what do you want to do with the values of the rows having the same ids. You said you don't want duplicates but you did not explain what to do with the values of duplicates (keep the first value, concatenate, add if it is a integer, ...). Let's consider we want to keep the value associated with the first row met.

So you could do like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File inputFolder = new File("yourFolderPath");
    Set<String> alreadyMetNames = new HashSet<>();
    File output = File.createTempFile("output", ".csv");
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output); BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
        bw.write("Id,Name,Number");
        bw.newLine();
        for (File file : inputFolder.listFiles()) {
            try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
                String line;

                // Search the header line
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.startsWith("Id")) break;
                }

                // Start to parse the file at the first row containing data
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] split = line.split(",");
                    if (alreadyMetNames.add(split[1])) {// If the name has not already been met
                        bw.write(line);
                        bw.newLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Your file is here : " + output.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

This piece of code create a writer for your new file concatening the content of the other files. Then it iterates on each files you have, search the header row and finally write the content of the data below the header row to the final output file. While writing row it takes care of not rewritting rows for id already met.